# Do I need to create a specific user account per domain alias?

Tags: google-workspace

My question here is about domain aliases and how it is managed in Google Apps.

- My Google Apps account is set with the domain `domain.fr`
- I have my account `user@domain.fr`.

If a create a `domain.com` alias, do I need to create a `user@domain.com` account (and pay for it), or will all the emails sent to `user@domain.com` be automaticly redirected to my `user@domain.fr` account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the google support page:

> If you have a domain alias for your primary domain, every user and group with an email address in the primary domain (user@primary.com) automatically has an email alias address in the alias domain (user@domainalias.com).

You don't need to create a new user *or* a new alias, and all emails will be redirected to the associated user's inbox. As it is an email alias there is no cost.